# How to get date row difference in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this below

table1

```
+----+---------------------------+
| Id |           Date            |
+----+---------------------------+
| 12 | 2019-04-20 12:35:00.000   |
|  2 | 2019-04-20 12:55:00.000   |
| 11 | 2019-04-20 11:57:00.000   |
|  7 | 2019-04-20 12:00:00.000   |
|  5 | 2019-04-20 12:05:00.000   |
+----+---------------------------+
```

i want to get output like below

```
+----+-------------------------+-------+
| Id |          Date           | Diff  |
+----+-------------------------+-------+
| 12 | 2019-04-20 12:35:00.000 | NULL  |
|  2 | 2019-04-20 12:55:00.000 | 00:20 |
| 11 | 2019-04-20 11:57:00.000 | 23:02 |
|  7 | 2019-04-20 12:00:00.000 | 00:03 |
|  5 | 2019-04-20 12:05:00.000 | 00:05 |
+----+-------------------------+-------+
```

I have tried with below query;

```
SELECT id, Date, 
  DATEDIFF((SELECT MAX(Date) FROM Event 
    WHERE Date < t.Date), Date ) AS days_since_last 
FROM Event AS t;
```

Please help anyone help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain how to get your expected output and include a query that you've tested. Thanks.

Comment: i have tried with below query SELECT
  id,
  Date,
  DATEDIFF(
    (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM Event WHERE Date < t.Date),
    Date
  ) AS days_since_last
FROM Event AS t

Answer (score 0):

`DATEDIFF` returns days differences between two dates. If you're looking to find time differences, you use `TIMEDIFF`:

```
SELECT id, DATE, 
  TIMEDIFF((SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM Event),DATE) AS days_since_last 
FROM Event AS t;
```

I also remove `WHERE Date < t.Date` from `SELECT MAX(Date) FROM Event WHERE Date < t.Date`. Because if I understand correctly, what you want is the time difference between the latest time with any of the previous time, correct? If not, please let me know and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Thank you.

**Update:** So, my initial understanding was wrong (again.. ) and it turns out that the sub-query was correct. In that case, there are only two changes I made from the OP's original query:

```
SELECT id, DATE, 
  TIMEDIFF(DATE,(SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM Event 
    WHERE DATE < t.Date)) AS days_since_last 
FROM Event AS t;
```

I only change `DATEDIFF` to `TIMEDIFF` and the order of the dates in `TIMEDIFF(date1,date2)`.

Comment: i want to get second (2nd id-1st id,3rd-2nd id) -first,third-second i need to get.

Comment: If that the case, your `SELECT MAX(Date) FROM Event WHERE Date < t.Date` was correct then. Let me update my answer.

Comment: it worked with below command                                                                    
 SELECT Table.ID, Table.DATE, TIMEDIFF(Table.DATE, t2.DATE),TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(Table.DATE, t2.DATE))
 FROM Table
 LEFT JOIN Table AS t2 ON t2.ID = Table.ID - 1